# Android: how to debug app's start-up process

Tags: android, process, startup, ddms

I am investigating some issues which happen during my app's startup process, but DDMS won't start the debug mode until the process *has* started, is there a way I can capture the events earlier?

Comment: never mind, I just put WaitForDebugger in the code, which can let me debug the launching process.

Answer (score 19):

I know that this is a couple of years late, but for any future searches:

Putting `WaitForDebugger` into your code is one way.

Unlocking developer options (by tapping on the build number in system information on the android device) in Settings allows us to select an application for debugging and then opt to wait for a debugger whenever the program is launched.  This allows us do the equivalent of adding and removing `WaitForDebugger` without modifying and reinstalling the code each time.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. I needed to have the debugger attached to an app before it starts, when invoked from Google Assistant.

Comment: Very short on detail…

Answer (score 14):

For Android Studio, here is what worked for me:

1. Add

> android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();

Where you want to start debugging.

2. Then add a breakpoint just after it in your code
3. Compile your app and pass it to your device
4. Restart your device
5. Once it's up, attach the debugger:[image]
6. Start debugging

Answer (score 4):

Android can wait for the debugger to attach to your application before the app gets launched. This is a developer option called **Wait for debugger**.

### Steps

- Enable developer options (tap build version 7 times)
- Enable USB debugging
- Install your application onto your device using debug mode
- In developer options: Press <kbd>Select debug app</kbd> and select the app
- Enable <kbd>Wait for debugger</kbd>, as shown in screenshot:
  [image]
- **Launch your app:**

  - e.g. If testing app launch from terminated state from a push notification, send that push notification to the device.
  - e.g. If testing app launch from Google Assistant, use the Google Assistant to trigger this.
- The app would not launch yet, instead a dialog would show up:
  [image]
- Attach the debugger, by pressing the <kbd>Attach Debugger to Android Process</kbd> button
  [image]

### My situation

For anyone interested/ for my future reference: I wanted to debug my Android application receiving a push notification message when the app was in the **terminated state**. It was actually a Flutter app running on Android, so this is relevant for both Android and Flutter.

[image]

I have revoked the API key revealed in this GIF.

### Tip

If <kbd>Wait for debugger</kbd> is enabled, sometimes you need to detach or close Android Studio's debugger and re-attach it if you want to handle a subsequent application launch successfully. Otherwise, the app would never launch.

Notice, I send a push notification from a device (left device, iOS), and the push notification causes the app to launch on the (right device, Android). Then I attach the debugger, and the program pauses at the breakpoint I set inside `FirebaseMessagingReceiver`.

I wrote another version of these steps [here](https://orth.uk/debug-android-and-flutter-from-launch).

Comment: I know that this only duplicates a much older answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/30533066/334719), but that answer is woefully insufficient in detail.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement your own Application class which extends 
Application and override the methods onCreate and so.. . This class will be your starting point of your app.

also set it as your application in the manifest.

Comment: add there the `android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();` Statement. like in @hiddeneyes02 -Answer